# If $f \in C^\infty (\mathbb{R})$ such that $f^{(n)}=0$ for some $n$, then $f$ is a polynomial?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, taylor-expansion, baire-category

Just as in the title, suppose $f \in C^\infty ((a,b),\mathbb{R})$ such that $f^{(n)}=0$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Prove that $f$ is a polynomial.

My solution to this is to use the Taylor expansion about some $a\in\mathbb{R}$, so that $f(x) = f(a) + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{f'(a)}{k!}(x-a)^k + \frac{f^{(n)}(\xi)}{n!}(x-a)^n$, but since $f^{(n)}$ is identically zero, we simply have that $f(x) = f(a) + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{f'(a)}{k!}(x-a)^k$.

I'm pretty sure this solution is incorrect, however, since this question has been asked on this site and the solution involves the Baire Category Theorem and other subtle analysis/topology arguments. I'm sure if someone had seen this solution, the question would not have gotten 100+ upvotes on mathoverflow. So what's wrong with this argument? Or is it correct?

Also does it make a difference if $f\in C^\infty([a,b];\mathbb{R})$ as opposed to $C^\infty((a,b);\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Just because $f$ is $C^\infty$ does not mean it equals its Taylor expansion.

Comment: That's true, but since $f^{(n)} = 0 \implies f^{(k)} = 0$ for all $k \ge n$, it is clear to see that this particular $f$ does equal its Taylor series

Comment: This is trivial. The harder problem is proving that if for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists an $n_{x} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f^{(n)}(x) = 0$, then $f$ is a polynomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The question you mention](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34059/if-f-is-infinitely-differentiable-then-f-coincides-with-a-polynomial) has a different hypothesis, where $f^{(n)}(x)=0$, but $n$ may vary with $x$.

If you only require $f^{(n)}=0$ (for all $x$), then you can easily prove by induction that if $f^{(k+1)}$ is a polynomial, then so is $f^{(k)}$, with the degree increased by one. For starters, if $f^{(n)}=0$, then $f^{(n-1)}$ is constant. And so on.

Your argument does work. It is just more complex than what is needed here.

Comment: Aha! $n$ varies with $x$. That's exactly the difference in the hypothesis I was looking for! Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: It is continuous, hence integrable, hence $f^{(n-1)}(x)=A$, hence $f^{(n-2)}(x)=Ax+B$ and so on.